# How can I fetch CouchDB server version via PouchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

All I want to get is this object:

```json
{
  "couchdb": "Welcome",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "git_sha": "ce596c65d",
  "uuid": "ff0e85a5e76efdf116e1394e1a94a70f",
  "features": [
    "access-ready",
    "partitioned",
    "pluggable-storage-engines",
    "reshard",
    "scheduler"
  ],
  "vendor": { "name": "The Apache Software Foundation" }
}
```

But I can't figure out how can I fetch the root server URL.

Maybe there is another option in PouchDB how to get CouchDB server version.

EDIT:

I have found this function is source code, but it doesn't get info described in the comment above the function. [GitHub link](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/9519c748c48cbac41451039765c758e5987bbc57/packages/node_modules/pouchdb-adapter-http/src/index.js#L423)

```js
  // Calls GET on the host, which gets back a JSON string containing
  //    couchdb: A welcome string
  //    version: The version of CouchDB it is running
  api._info = function (callback) {
    setup().then(function () {
      return ourFetch(genDBUrl(host, ''));
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (info) {
      info.host = genDBUrl(host, '');
      callback(null, info);
    }).catch(callback);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a digging a bit into the source code, I have found the solution.

```js
infoDb
      .fetch('/')
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('FETCH', res);
      });
```

Result:

```json
{
    "couchdb": "Welcome",
    "version": "3.1.1",
    "git_sha": "ce596c65d",
    "uuid": "ff0e85a5e76efdf116e1394e1a94a70f",
    "features": [
        "access-ready",
        "partitioned",
        "pluggable-storage-engines",
        "reshard",
        "scheduler"
    ],
    "vendor": {
        "name": "The Apache Software Foundation"
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar using fetch as pouchDB and nano don't provide for the root endpoint, Good answer, accept it!